# Parse.com not working on OSX (Swift)

Tags: macos, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to use Parse.com SDK in my Mac OSX app written in swift. I have followed the Quickstart Guide and used a bridging header but when I launch the app I am shown this message and the object is not created on launch.

```
Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, for some reason the viewDidLoad() on the view controllers are executing before the app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching: method.

Although Parse recommends having their methods setup in the app delegate, setting up the app id/client key on your initial view's viewDidLoad will let you use parse normally.